Flutter expandable row, sortable, filterable data table
Is this crazy of a design or is it possible? Collapsable row of main table, and under main table is secondary table with matching ID, different column numbers. Each has their own header. I want at least maint table header is sortable and filterable.  Image of expandable/collapsable rows but from different table, matching ID
I've been circling trying to apply this to sfdatagrid, however most end result whether they are mushed to a single column or all few lines to a single row. I did manage using grouping however you cant filter, sort, or change behaviour much with a grouping caption. The header are also a whole another story of mess.
Is this a bad design or just impossible to do?

Check pluto_grid here https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_grid

You can checkout these libraries to design the UI with the functionality you want - Flutter Expandable Table, additionally, this SO Answer also suggests a few packages that can help in achieving the use case you are looking for - SO Answer
